# Trying to convert datetime in date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i'm trying to convert date 01-03-2020 10:48:27 which obtained from query

```
 SELECT
  LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3 ) )+1
FROM
  dual;
```

into '01-Mar-2020' but not able to do trying many concept
eg.

```
trunc(SELECT  LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE , - 3 ) )+1 FROM  dual),'YEAR')
```

and

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('SELECT  LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE , - 3 ) )+1 FROM  dual','DD-MON-YY'), 'YEAR')  "New Year" FROM DUAL;
```

but getting error
Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Is the format important, as in `'01-Mar-2020'`? Or are you just trying to truncate the date (keep the same date component, set the time-of-day component to 00:00:00), but with the result still in **date** data type, not string? `trunc` is used for the latter, not the former; and it is applied directly to the date calculated in the first query. That is: `select trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -3)) + 1) from dual;` Or, you can simply apply `trunc` to `sysdate` upfront: `... add_months(trunc(sysdate), 3) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Convert" in your case means `TO_CHAR`; `alter session` is here to set default format for this session.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select
  2            last_Day(add_months(sysdate, -3)) + 1 orig,
  3    to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -3)) + 1, 'dd-Mon-yyyy', 'nls_Date_language = english') result
  4  from dual;

ORIG                RESULT
------------------- --------------------
01.03.2020 07:25:44 01-Mar-2020

SQL>
```

---

Or, if you *altered* the session, you'd get it as

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-Mon-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select
  2            last_Day(add_months(sysdate, -3)) + 1 orig
  3  from dual;

ORIG
-----------
01-Mar-2020

SQL>
```

But, yes - usually we `TO_CHAR` it.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because I consider the other answer superior. Its last paragraph is most important: dates (and numbers) should be converted to strings by whatever program is closest to the user's screen. That program is not the same for us developers and for end users!

Comment: Sure, @Stew, no problem, you can do whatever you want. I just wonder - when you visit *discussions*, do you upvote one and downvote all other replies (the ones you find inferior to the one you found superior)? From my point of view, it is OK to upvote answer you think is the best, but - downvoting others (which, by the way, seem to do what was asked) doesn't seem to be right. As I said: you can do & comment what you want, and so can I.

Comment: Littlefoot, your reaction is understandable and gracefully expressed. Please consider the content of my comment: first, implicit or explicit conversion of dates to strings is done way too often; second, SQL statements that are destined to be submitted from application programs should return the original data types (they are then converted to usable data types by the Oracle driver).

Answer (score 3):

You're making things way too complicated. Oracle TRUNC takes an additional parameter to specify whatever time interval to truncate to:

```
SELECT TRUNC(some_date_here, 'MON') FROM dual
```

If you put some_date_here as sysdate, then currently it will return 01-May-2020 until next month when it starts returning 01-Jun-2020

You can truncate to any interval; TRUNC 01/01/2000 12:34:56 with 'MI' will return 01/01/2000 12:34:00. Truncating to DD is the default (cut the time off). Truncating to DAY sets the date back to the day that started the week in the country oracle thinks it is in (probably a Sunday or Monday)

More info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084

As I understood your problem you want to go from the current date, to the first of the month that was between 2 and < 3 months ago (so if it's May now, you want to go back to first of March until it's June, when you want to go back to first of April)

If you hence, in the current date of 5th May, want to go back to a date of 1 March, take 2 months off the current date and then TRUNC to the start of the month:

```
SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -2), 'MON') FROM dual
```

Don't forget you can TRUNC to the nearest quarter of a year, so if you're doing a report that is "the current quarter", then looking at a variation of TRUNC(sysdate, 'Q') would be the way to go

Lastly, I'd urge you NOT to use oracle to convert your dates to strings (in most cases) - if you keep it as a date all the way 'tIl it hits the user's computer it can be formatted for their regional preferences. If you make a decision as to the format as its coming out the dB it makes it much harder to deliver a good international experience for your app

Comment: err... no, the OP is looking back **three** months - which is why his desired result is 1 March, not 1 May. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my use of sysdate as a recommendation to put sysdate into his code - it's just a date to demonstrate the use of TRUNC, but if it confused you it will confuse others so I'll change it

Comment: @CaiusJard I think if you just made the code relevant to the question e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7de9f9b6753d72f248075ec9eea0618 it would be more obvious what you're saying

Comment: No, my objection had nothing to do with `sysdate`, but with the use of truncating to `month` when the OP wanted a date related to "three months ago". While his computation is indeed clumsy, simply using `trunc(... , 'month')` wasn't going to do it.

Comment: @mathguy But he demonstrated he already knew how to use ADD_MONTHS, he just didn't seem to know you could TRUNC the days off a date, because he's going back 3 then going forward to the last day, then adding a day etc. Anyhow, would you kindly review the changes made to the answer and reconsider your downvote? Advocating date-string-date conversion just to cut portions of a time off is seldom a good way to do it; TRUNC can and should be used to handle this

Comment: I already removed my downvote. Your re-writing of the whole computation is fine now. With that said:  It's not clear (yet) what the OP really meant to do - to get a **date** or a **string** in the output. You can see my comment under his question, which I posted before you posted your original answer. :-)

Comment: Well, I think it's worth upvoting. Easy enough to transform this into a string and it is *far* superior to `LAST_DAY( ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3 ) )+1`